# How to differ between a parameterless and a string-parameter mvc action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Today I found it hard to discover the difference between two MVC action methods.

My arearegistration:

```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
  {
     // My test route.
     context.MapRoute(
         "testRoute",
         "Test/{action}",
         new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
     );
  }
```

And the two methods, that differ from both the used http-method and the parameter.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Test(TestModel model)
  {
     return View("Confirm", model);
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Test(string title)
  {
     Response.Write(title);
     Response.End();

     return null;
  }
```

Unregarded the http method, it will always end up rendering the second Test() method. Even when no title parameter is supplied (normally by querystring /Test/Test/?title=test). Probably because string is a reference type and can be null.

But how to overcome this problem? How to make a difference between these methods?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow this signature, basically always use the 'GET' method signature with the model as last parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string title, TestModel model)
```

By the way, I've never seen the behavior you've mentioned. So I doubt whether this is a MVC problem rather than something in your configuration. [HttpGet] methods never fire on a POST method. Is the method really post (check the Request property of your ControllerContext).

Comment: Allright, you're right. Thanks!! Didn't test it through properly!! Those http attributes really do the job. But imagine the http attributes can't be used, then it's really impossible to differentiate from the two methods, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. You can see it if you want to call the method (f.e. in a unittest) by calling `Test(null);`. You will have to box explicitly, otherwise the compiler will fail. So something like `Test((string)null);`.